# jquery effect works in jfiddle but not online - help please

Tags: jquery, effect

Still trying to solve this after many hours. The script works in jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uCcYw/3/ ,apply flash effect to parent of add_item (simplecart_shelfitem), but not online: http://www.diysoakwells.com.au/test.html. Its the same code copied and pasted, i dont get it !! PLease help : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put it inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // some code here
 });
```

Comment: @user1292064 please mark this as answered if it has answered your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
(function() {
    $(".item_add").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().effect("highlight", {}, 750);

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

to

```
$(function() {
    $(".item_add").click(function() {     
        $(this).parent().effect("highlight", {}, 750);       
        return false;
    });
})
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/gtT4H/7/

Comment: Careful, apprently someone thinks this is a downvotable answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Thanks . But i dont think there is something here to get a downvote. I think even your answer is correct. +1 for that.

Comment: Neither do I, but obviously someone doesn't understand shortcut ready handlers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I added the same comment to your answer. I feel $(function is simple and more readable that document.ready

Answer (score 0):

You haven't wrapped your JavaScript in a [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) call. The element with the specified class doesn't exist at the point of JS execution.

Answer (score 0):

Your ready handler is missing the `$` from the start:

```
$(function() {
    $(".item_add").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().effect("highlight", {}, 750);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Rami.Shareef pointed out the obvious reason, it works without the $. Can you point me in the direction of some info about when to use the $ ?

Comment: You already had a ready handler, you'd just put a typo in it.

Comment: @user1292064 : $(function()  is the short form of document.ready. So this answer also is correct.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, yeah just tested it and it breaks it. does this mean if i had the $ and no `$(document).ready(function() {` it would be ok?

Comment: @user1292064 : Check the link in my answer.I am also using $(function ( which is shortform of document ready) and it is working fine.